# How to use Bootstrap in aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Store.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:content id="Content1" contentplaceholderid="head" runat="Server">
</asp:content>
<asp:content id="Content2" contentplaceholderid="StoreMasterPlaceHolder" runat="Server">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="tblBodySides">
                <div class="bodyDiv">
                    <!-- left Column -->
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tblBodySides">
                                <h4>
                                    look at our fantastic events
                                    <br />
                                    book one for today !
                                    <br />
                                    <hr />
                                </h4>
                                <h3>
                                    Events</h3>
                                <asp:calendar runat="server" class="cal" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td class="tblBodySides left_bord">
                                <h3>
                                    Here Are list of our Items colors:</h3>
                                <asp:gridview runat="server" id="gw1" datasourceid="XmlDataSource1">
                                </asp:gridview>
                                <asp:xmldatasource id="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" datafile="~/App_Data/items.xml">
                                </asp:xmldatasource>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="tblBodyCenter">
            </td>
            <td class="tblBodySides">
                <div class="bodyDiv">
                    <!-- Right Column -->
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="sides">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <h3>
                                    Definitions:
                                    <br />
                                    <hr />
                                </h3>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <h2>
                                            CSS
                                        </h2>
                                    </li>
                                    <p class="justified left_bord">
                                    BLA BLA BLA</p>
                                   <br />
                                </ul>
                            </td>

                            <td class="sides">

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:content>
```

I want to use bootstrap in a page above.

Where do I put this rows in above:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside this section:

```
 <asp:content id="Content1" contentplaceholderid="head" runat="Server">
 </asp:content>
```

Because this is the content area for content that should be placed in the head section of your resulting HTML page. That's why the id is 'head'.

Answer (score 0):

If You are using Master Page then Please Write the Link code to stylesheet in Master Page,after this we dont want to use link code for each page just use that Master Page.